# Increment value from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have entries that look like this:

[image: 1]

Before the data is inputted, the barcode must be filled using a barcode scanner. When a barcode is existing in Firestore, I want product quantity is increase. And when the barcode is not available in Firestore, Intent to another class.

Code :

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String scanResult = result.getText();

    ToneGenerator toneNotification = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);
    toneNotification.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP, 150);

    collectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    // if barcode is existing, then product quantity to increment
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("barCode") != null) {
                        collectionReference.document(queryDocumentSnapshot.getId()).update("productQuantity", FieldValue.increment(1));
                        Intent moveView = new Intent(ScannersActivity.this, ViewData.class);
                        moveView.putExtra("documentID", documentID);
                        startActivity(moveView);
                        finish();
                    } else { // If barcode is not available in firestore, then intent to another class
                        Intent moveCode = new Intent(ScannersActivity.this, AddItems.class);
                        moveCode.putExtra("sendDocumentID", documentID);
                        moveCode.putExtra("ScanResult", scanResult);
                        startActivity(moveCode);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to perform a simple Cloud Firestore query.  The documentation is the best place to start learning about how that works.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: What is the exact value that you need to increment, `productQuantity`? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: yap i want when barcode is existing in firestore then productQuantity to increment @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increment the value of your `productQuantity` property based on the existence of the `barCode` property, please try the following lines of code:

```
collectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.getString("barCode") != null) {
                    collectionReference.document(document.getId()).update(
                        "productQuantity", FieldValue.increment(1)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: without whereEqualTo? Like this, collectionReference.whereEqualTo("barCode", scanResult).addOnCompleteListener......

Comment: Yes, without. There is no need for a query and whereEqual call, you can simply check the existents of a property. If it exists, simply increment it. Have you tried the code above?

Comment: i set onClick button, button cannot be clicked. i'll share my code in my question, wait...

Comment: It sounds like you should ask another question that explains what isn't working the way you expect in case of `onClick`. Please note that this question is not related with the initial one. so please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I also rolled back your edit since the data that you added made this question to be a new one.

Comment: i confuse with productsRef, what is that? can u explain? is it same with collectionReference?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it was a typo. Just updated my answer, where it should be `collectionReference` instead of `productsRef`. Does it work now?

Comment: still not work, can i change Fieldvalue.increment(1).toString? because i set productQuantity in pojo is String or should i change to Long?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yes, you should definitely **change** the type of the productQuantity property to be **long**. It does solve the problem, right?

Comment: **"still not working"** doesn't help me, help you solve the issue. What the behaviour, do you have an error? I have personally tested that code and worked fine.

Comment: i changed the code that you can see above, where is my mistake?

Comment: Alex, i'm so sorry the code is working. evidently, condition "else" for intent to another activity is not working

Answer (score 0):

This will figure out if the barcode exists. You can fill in the commented `TODO` with a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to update the quantity value.

```java
public void handleResult(Result result) {
  String scanResult = result.getText();
  // ...

  collectionReference
    .whereEqualTo("barCode", scanResult)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult().size() > 0) {
          // TODO barcode exists; increase qty
        }
        else {
          // barcode not found, new Intent
        }
      }
    });
}
```